# Is the Catholic Magesterium in favor of hard liquor prohibition?

Tags: catholicism, alcohol, asia

As long as I've been a fairly globally aware Catholic, I'd always projected G.K. Chesterton's

> We should thank God for Beer and Burgundy by not drinking too much of them

as a universal maxim enjoyed by the whole church towards temperance, but not "extreme temperance".  But [this article](http://www.ncregister.com/daily-news/indian-state-okays-prohibition/) in the National Catholic Register struck me as odd.  Apparently Bishops in India are lobbying against all sales of hard liquor, and winning (probably because of the combined support of Islam against all alcohol?).

I wasn't aware that there was anything eviler in rum than in wine or beer.  But is this just a local cause for a local purpose or, given the opportunity would Bishops everywhere be likely to oppose the sale of hard liquor?

Answer (score 4):

> [...] All their efforts must aim at **preserving the true faith and a
>   high moral tone among the people**; they attain this end by good
>   example, by preaching, by daily solicitude for the good administration
>   of the diocese, and by prayer. [...] - [Obligations of the bishop |
>   Bishop | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02581b.htm).

Therefore it is within the rights and obligations of Archbishop Cardinal Baselios mar Cleemis, president of the Catholic Bishops Conference of India and head of the Catholic Church in Kerala, to publicly caution the government of **“grave consequences if it yielded to the liquor lobby and reopened the closed bars.”** - Read more: [Indian State Okays Prohibition](http://www.ncregister.com/daily-news/indian-state-okays-prohibition/#ixzz3D2ho3CCX).